# Does MacBook Pro 13 2017 support a Logitech BRIO 4K Webcam?

Tags: macbook-pro, webcam

I want to buy the [Logitech BRIO Webcam with 4K Ultra HD Video & HDR](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/webcams/brio-4k-hdr-webcam.960-001105.html).

However, I'm not sure it will work with my [MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017)](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP753).

Could anyone say if it will work? If 4K is too much for it, can it work better in a lower resolution using the same webcam?

Comment: Always read right through *all* details when getting Logitech for Macs - sometimes they don't mention the bits that don't work until right at the end. Start at https://prosupport.logi.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360040085833 & go right through it before committing.

Comment: Case in point. I got a C920 when it was the 'latest, greatest' thing, in about 2012. It took them maybe 5 or 6 years to add proper Mac support & it's still very basic. I've been running the cam off a 3rd party app to this day. It struggles to reach 10 fps, even so.

Answer (score 1):

The system requirements are included in the link you posted.

- macOS® 10.10 or later
- 2 GB RAM or more needed for 1080p video streaming, 1GB is typically needed for streaming 720p

So you should be able to at least use it with 1080p. The site does not specify specific requirements on 4K streaming - it should generally work but the performance may vary depending on other load on your system while using it.